# HTML: how to properly set header for nesting <article>

Tags: html, accessibility, semantic-ui

I'm creating a React component which represents a product card. Each product card has a title and a list of sub-product cards, and so on. This nested structure can go infinitively.

At this stage my focus is on having a correct structure, outline and utilizing semantic HTML.

[According to MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/article), `<article>` is a correct element to represent this. So I've come up with this structure:

```
<h1> Products </h1>
<article>
    <header>
        <h2> Title: Product A </h2>
    </header>
    <div>
        <span>Sub-products:</span>
        <ul>
            <li>
                <article>
                    <header>
                        <h2> Title: Product A-1 </h2>
                    </header>
                    <div>
                        <span>Sub-products:</span>
                        <ul>
                            <li>
                                <article>
                                    <header>
                                        <h2> Title: Product A-1-1 </h2>
                                    </header>
                                </article>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </article>
            </li>
            <li>
                <article>
                    <header>
                        <h2> Title: Product A-2 </h2>
                    </header>
                </article>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</article>
```

Now, I'm wondering if using `h2` correct at all. I was thinking about using `h3`-`h6` but what actually stopped me was that after 6 level of nesting, I wouldn't have a proper tag to use.

So, what's the correct way to present titles as the heading of the articles?

Comment: How many levels deep are you expecting to be? If you are getting 5 levels deep perhaps there is a much bigger problem with the data and you need to flatten the way it is presented. FYI there is `role=heading` and `aria-level` that actually goes to 7 if that happens to fix the issue for you. The above is technically correct and valid HTML, it just seems a nightmare to navigate and not very useful for screen readers.

Comment: My understanding is that the level of support offered by browsers and assistive-technology for `<article>` is very poor.  I tested using NVDA on Windows, and the screen reader doesn't recognize `<article>` or `<section>` in any meaningful way.  While it's certainly valid HTML, if your goal is to provide a good level of accessibility, I'd recommend going another route. You can do your own testing here: https://dequeuniversity.com/assets/html/jquery-summit/html5/slides/landmarks-example.html

Comment: Also some good test results on screen-reader support for sectioning elements here: https://www.accessibilityoz.com/2020/02/html5-sectioning-elements-and-screen-readers/

Comment: @GrahamRitchie Tried your suggestion with NVDA and JAWS; NVDA honors `aria-level`; However in JAWS, `aria-level` greater than 6 is read like `aria-level=2` which makes me think it's a bug. All in all, I believe your suggestion is the right route to take.

Answer (score -1):

If you nest contents using `<article>`, use `<h1>` for the title of each article: Right -- more than one `<h1>` in the code for one HTML page.

Bruce Lawson wrote a comprehensive article about this subject:
https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2020/01/html5-article-section/

```
<h1> Products </h1>
<article>
    <header>
        <h1> Title: Product A </h1>
    </header>
    <div>
        <span>Sub-products:</span>
        <ul>
            <li>
                <article>
                    <header>
                        <h1> Title: Product A-1 </h1>
                    </header>
                    <div>
                        <span>Sub-products:</span>
                        <ul>
                            <li>
                                <article>
                                    <header>
                                        <h1> Title: Product A-1-1 </h1>
                                    </header>
                                </article>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </article>
            </li>
            <li>
                <article>
                    <header>
                        <h1> Title: Product A-2 </h1>
                    </header>
                </article>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</article>
```

That said, my preferred approach is actually use `aria-labelledBy` to connect those `<h1>`s as the title of each segment, i.e.:

```
 <h1> Products </h1>
    <article aria-labelledBy="title001">
        <header>
            <h1 id="title001"> Title: Product A </h1>
        </header>
        <div>
            <span>Sub-products:</span>
            <ul>
                <li>
                    <article aria-labelledBy="title002">
                        <header>
                            <h1 id="title002"> Title: Product A-1 </h1>
                        </header>
                        <div>
                            <span>Sub-products:</span>
                            <ul>
                                <li>
                                    <article aria-labelledBy="title003">
                                        <header>
                                            <h1 id="title003"> Title: Product A-1-1 </h1>
                                        </header>
                                    </article>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    </article>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <article  aria-labelledBy="title004">
                        <header>
                            <h1 id="title004"> Title: Product A-2 </h1>
                        </header>
                    </article>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </article>
```

Arguably it's a little elaborative, but creates unmistakable link between each piece of content and its title when accessed with accessible technologies -- even when the segment is tab-navigated into with no chance to read its `<h1>` element.

Comment: The article you linked actually says not to start again with h1s inside each `<section>` or `<article>` because browsers don't implement this properly for the accessibility tree